# php- cannot compare curl_exec result

Tags: php, php-curl

I am using PHP cURL to make a GET request using:

```
$ch  = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "url here");
curl_Setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$exec = curl_exec ($ch);
```

When I try to echo  `$exec` it displays 1 but when I do:

```
if ($exec == '1') {
    echo 'Done';
} else {
    echo 'API returned an error:'.$exec;
}
```

It always displays the following, even if the output returned by the GET request is 1, 2 or anything:

```
API returned an error:1
```

What's wrong?

Comment: What is `var_dump($exec);`?

Comment: `var_dump($exec)`. your `1` may not actually be a 1. it could be `1[space]` or `1[linebreak]` or something, which would fail your string test.

Comment: var_dump gives `string(3) "1 " `

Comment: yes there's an space/ let me try

Comment: var_dump() worked, it had an space. thanks :)